# One jQuery animation after another

Tags: jquery

Say I have 2 animation buttons on a page. A user clicks on the first animation and it animates into place. I have it so the animation opens up and it stays there until the user clicks on somewhere else on the page. But when the user clicks on another animation trigger button while the other animation is still up, everything screws up and both animations go at the same time :(. So how would I delay the other animation until the closing animation on the animation is done?
 Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hBb9L/17/

```
$("#e").click(function (e) {
    //done
    $("#re").animate({
        "margin-top": "104px"
    }, 800);
    $("#ret").animate({
        "margin-top": "104px"
    }, 800);
    $(".popu").animate({
        "margin-top": "-102px"
    }, 800);
    $("#s").show(200);
    e.stopPropagation();
```

Wow, thank you for reading all that!

Comment: Which version of jQuery UI? Can you show us the code you have for the click event handlers?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use jquery promise().

http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Answer (score 0):

In the properties for `animate()`, make sure you set `queue: true`. This will add the animation for the next click to the end of the animation queue, meaning it will execute after the current animation completes instead of immediately.

For example, if I had two buttons that moved a test div left and right a bit:

```
<button type="button" id="moveLeft">Left</button>
<button type="button" id="moveRight">Right</button>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Style the box a bit:

```
#test {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    top: 50px;
    background: #f00;
    position: fixed;
}
```

And then had this JavaScript to hook up the events:

```
var $box = $('#test');

$('#moveRight').click(function() {
    $box.animate({
        queue: true,
        left: "+=50"
    });
});

$('#moveLeft').click(function() {
    $box.animate({
        queue: true,
        left: "-=50"
    });
});
```

You'll see that if you click the buttons one right after the other, the animations queue up and run only after the current one completes.

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2f2Vz/)**

Comment: Err... as the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) says, the default value for the `queue` option is already `true`.

Comment: @Cory I updated the question with a jfiddle and it still wont work could you look at it?